# Same binary pattern match of elixir got different representations on command line

Tags: binary, pattern-matching, elixir

I'm new to Elixir and confused by the two different outputs of line15 and line17 below, ie., one is `98` and the other is `"b"`(from the [offical document](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#binaries)).

These two matchs just do the same thing, since(IMO) `<<head, rest::binary>>` is identical to `<<head::binary-size(1), rest::binary>>`. Why they differ on the output? (I know they're same internally)

I'm using Windows OS BTW.

```
iex(14)> <<head, rest::binary>> = "banana"
"banana"
iex(15)> head
98
iex(16)> <<head::binary-size(1), rest::binary>> = "banana"
"banana"
iex(17)> head
"b"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default type for the [element in bitstring](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#%3C%3C%3E%3E/1) is `integer`, but when you explicitly specify it to be pattern-matched as `binary`, it becomes `binary`.

```erlang
iex|1> <<head::integer, rest::binary>> = "banana"
iex|2> head
#⇒ 98
iex|3> <<head>>
#⇒ "b"
```